# Why can't I delete multiple entries from bash history with this loop

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, history

This loop will display what I want to do but if I remove the `echo` from it, it won't actually delete anything:

```
history | grep ":[0-5][0-9] ls *$" | cut -c1-5 | 
while read id; do 
    echo history -d $id
done
```

I've added indentation in order to make it more readable but I am running it as a one-liner from the command line.

I have `HISTTIMEFORMAT` set so the grep finds the seconds followed by `ls` followed by an arbitrary number of spaces.  Essentially, it's finding anything in history that's just an `ls`.

This is using `bash 4.3.11` on `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`history -d` removes an entry from the in-memory history, and you are running it in a subshell induced by the pipe. That means you are removing a history entry from the subshell's history, not your current shell's history.

Use a process substitution to feed the loop:

```
while read id; do
    history -d "$id"
done < <(history | grep ":[0-5][0-9] ls *$" | cut -c1-5)
```

or, if your version of `bash` is new enough, use the `lastpipe` option to ensure your `while` loop is executed in the current shell.

```
shopt -s lastpipe
history | grep ":[0-5][0-9] ls *$" | cut -c1-5 | 
while read id; do 
    echo history -d $id
done
```

Comment: Hmmm, neither seems to work.  Though, your explanation on why it doesn't work seems plausible.

Comment: Oh, right.  An earlier version of my command line had  a reverse sort to deal with this but I didn't put it in my question.  It works fine once I do that.

Comment: Good :) I deleted my previous comment because I wasn't convinced I had verified it sufficiently.