# How do I delete lines from my bash history matching a specific pattern?

Tags: bash, sed

I can get a list of the line numbers matching a specific pattern such as containing the word "function".

```
history | grep function | sed -e 's/^\(.\{5\}\).*/\1/' | sed 's/^ *//g'
```

If I do `history -d` on that it says bad pattern, I don't know if it's as it's a list or their strings rather than numbers?

```
history -d (history | grep function | sed -e 's/^\(.\{5\}\).*/\1/' | sed 's/^ *//g')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Quick answer:**

```
while read n; do history -d $n; done < <(history | tac | awk '/function/{print $1}')
```

**Explanation:**
The `history` command accepts only a single offset when using the `-d` flag. On top of that when you delete an entry, it also renumbers all the commands after this entry. For this reason we revert the output of `history` using `tac` and process the lines from last to first. This short `awk` line just replaces the grep and sed command to pick up the history offset.

We do not use a full pipeline as this creates subshells and `history -d $n` would not work properly. This is nicely explained in: [Why can't I delete multiple entries from bash history with this loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360534/why-cant-i-delete-multiple-entries-from-bash-history-with-this-loop)

**Note:** If you want to push this to your history file (`$HISTFILE`), you have to use `history -w`

**Warning:** When you have multiline commands in your history the story becomes very complicated and strongly depends on various options that have been set. See [[U&L] When is a multiline history entry (aka lithist) in bash possible?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/353386) for the nasty bits.

Comment: A caveat regarding multiline `history` entries when using this would be good.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks ... I did not think about that. It gets ugly quickly

Comment: Indeed. The ugly `awk` in my version is meant to fix it. Hopefully there's a nicer way. :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo be aware that the history output you have produced depends on the settings of `cmdhist` and `lithist` and even the time-format if you want. A single answer is not really easily possible.

Comment: No, one would need to write a script to set it up so all output becomes possible to parse - and even then I don't know if it'll be portable.

Comment: This appears to work from the bash shell, but in script form it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

You can delete one history entry or a range of entries, but not a list. Your matches are likely to be spread out, so the range option is out.

The multiple `sed` commands to extract the history offsets can be simplified into one:

```
sed -E 's/^ *([0-9]*).*$/\1/'
```

One problem with `history` is that it can have *multiline* entries, like:

```
741  source <(history | \
       grep function | \
       sed -E 's/^ *([0-9]*).*$/\1/' | \
       sort -rn | \
       xargs -n1 echo history -d)
```

If your `grep` matches on `function` above, your `sed` will not be able to extract the `history` offset number, so we need to make that possible. One way may be to remove all *newlines* and only add them on lines containing the `history` offset. This is one way that probably can be done in some easier way:

```
awk '/^ {0,4}[0-9]+/ {
  printf("\n%s",$0);
}
!/^ {0,4}[0-9]+/{
  printf(" %s",$0);
}
END{
  printf("\n")
}'
```

We can then produce a number of `history -d` commands with `xargs`. `xargs` can't run the build-it `history` directly, so I've just used it to produce input to the built-in `source` using [Process Substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
source <(history | \
         awk '/^ {0,4}[0-9]+/ {
           printf("\n%s",$0);
         }
         !/^ {0,4}[0-9]+/{
           printf(" %s",$0);
         }
         END{
           printf("\n")
         }' | \
         grep function | \
         sed -E 's/^ *([0-9]*).*$/\1/' | \
         sort -rn | \
         xargs -n1 echo history -d)
```

@kvantour gives nice alternatives to `grep` + `sed` + `sort -rn`. Using those, my above blob could be simplified into:

```
source <(history | \
         awk '/^ {0,4}[0-9]+/ {
           printf("\n%s",$0);
         }
         !/^ {0,4}[0-9]+/{
           printf(" %s",$0);
         }
         END{
           printf("\n")
         }' | \
         awk '/function/ {print "history -d",$1}' | \
         tac)
```

Comment: nice +1, I didn't know that you can do it this way

Comment: @lab9 Thanks! I had never deleted history entries myself previously so I had to try it out :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the pattern in a variable and then pass it to history.

```
$ history | grep function | sed -e 's/^\(.\{5\}\).*/\1/' | sed 's/^ *//g'
1077
$ var=$( history | grep function | sed -e 's/^\(.\{5\}\).*/\1/' | sed 's/^ *//g')
$ history -d $var
```

However, as you can have a lot of ocurrences for the patter, I would use a loop

```
$ var=$( history | grep function | sed -e 's/^\(.\{5\}\).*/\1/' | sed 's/^ *//g')
$ for i in $var
> do
> history -d $i
> history -w 
> done
```

If the line you want to delete has already been written to your $HISTFILE (which typically happens when you end a session by default), you will need to write back to $HISTFILE, or the line will reappear when you open a new session.

After the deletion you need to load again the .bashrc by executing

```
 $ cd
 $ source .bashrc
```

However, there are cases that the lines won't be deleted: if you set PROMPT_COMMAND to history -a, in that case it is already written to the history file, rather than on exit under normal configuration.

Comment: Did you verify that it deleted the correct entries?